# Could dark energy be linked to dark flow?

Tags: gravity, dark-energy

I couldn't find any other questions regarding [dark flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_flow) on Wikipedia, so I'm curious. As far as I can tell, [dark energy's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) existence seems to be hard to explain. Since there may be a couple of ideas that gravity isn't necessarily bound to our universe, is it possible that this dark flow, which may be gravitational pull from one (or more?) sibling universes is actually accountable for dark energy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dark flow is a theory related to different universes interacting, while dark energy relates to the arcana of how the empty space in just this one universe behaves. Coming from such different theoretical motivations, I don't think one can really be plugged into the other. Dark flow would also be confined to a particular region of space, while dark energy would be isotropic and homogeneous.